# create wordpress user on custom post type publish

Tags: custom-post-types

Trying to create user when custompostype is published, I have tried the following but its not working.

```
function adduseronpostpublish( $new_status, $old_status, $post )
            {
                if ( 'publish' !== $new_status or 'publish' === $old_status
                or 'custompostype' !== get_post_type( $post ) )
                return;


                function add_new_user_account(){
                $username = 'test'; //username
                $password = 'test'; //password
                $email = "user@user.com"; //email

                if ( !username_exists( $username )  && !email_exists( $email ) ) {
                $user_id = wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email );
                $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
                $user->set_role( 'contributor' ); //either of 'administrator', 'subscriber', 'editor', 'author', 'contributor'
                }
                }
                add_action('init','add_new_user_account');
            }

            }
            add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'adduseronpostpublish', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'wpse_206193_new_user_from_custom_post', 10, 3 );

function wpse_206193_new_user_from_custom_post( $new_status, $old_status, $post )
{
    if ( 'publish' !== $new_status or 'publish' === $old_status
        or 'my_custom_post' !== get_post_type( $post ) )
        return;

    $userdata = array(
        'user_login'    => 'user_name',
        'user_email'    => 'email@example.com',
        'user_pass'     =>  NULL,
        'role'          => 'contributor'
    );

    if ( !username_exists( $userdata['user_login'] )  && !email_exists( $userdata['user_email'] ) ) {
        wp_insert_user($userdata);
    }

}
```

You don't need to fire that `wp_create_user` on `init` or use a separate function in the function.